Embedd an existing WinForms Application into WinUI 3 Application
I wonder if it‘s somehow possible to embedd a classic WinForms Application inside a WinUI 3 Application, Like it was possible with WinFormsHost in a WPF Application?
The goal is to open WinForms Applications in a TabView in WinUI 3 and Switch between the opened WinForms Applications inside WinUI3
Thanks!
